# How do the hypnotizing glasses in Incredibles 2 work?

Tags: pixar, the-incredibles, incredibles-2

How do the hypnotizing glasses in the Incredibles 2 work? Do they work like possesion, Harry Potter-style? (Meaning they allow the glasses' controller to manipulate them like robots) I thought so, because the wearers' have no recollection of what happened to them while they were wearing them. But in one scene, a superhero clearly looks into the controller's screen face to face and gives him the details, implying that they are not like robots, and the controller does not know all the details of what's surrounding the controllee.
So how do the hypnotizing glasses work? (Other possibility - like Georgina in ASOUE. But that doesn't work fully either.)

Comment: if someone knows how to add spolier tags, please do so.

Comment: You get spoiler tags by putting `>!` at the start of the line. I would have put them in myself, but I don't know where the best place to do so is without rewording your question.

Answer (score 3):

I think you have the basic gist of it correct. From what I saw in the film, the goggles hypnotize the wearer, which allows the "Screen Slaver" to give instructions to those being controlled. The screens seemed to work both ways as well, giving a live feed back to the controller.

So while, orders could be given, i.e. "Go capture this person", and what the wearer sees the controller sees, the "Screen Slaver" did not have full control over the actions/movements of the wearer. Considering that numerous characters fall under control at the same time would make it impossible as well (Left hand is player one, right hand is player two, okay now I have to use my foot for player 3).

Answer (score 1):

Skooba is correct. Normally, Screenslaver just gives instructions to the people controlled. However, there is one instance where that seems to not be the case.

Right after Elastigirl discovers ...

> the real Screenslaver,

Screenslaver states that

> "He gave you a pretty good fight. I should say, I gave you a good fight through him."

This implies that Screenslaver was personally controlling the person who was fighting Elastagirl in a manner similar to "possession", even though Screenslaver does not do so in other instances.

Comment: This denotes that the "possession" is similar to Ultron in A:AoU, where he can inhabit any one of the drones at any time, but they can also serve his will autonomously. This is visually indicated by the blue inner glow turning orange. It makes me wonder if there is any similar visual cue to indicate that the Screenslaver is actively vs. passively controlling someone?